# Why does ApolloTestingModule in Angular spec file with jest throw: "Cannot read property 'use' of undefined?

Tags: jestjs, apollo, apollo-angular

I am trying to combine Angular, Jest and Apollo.

My Spec file follows the structure described in the documentation [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/guides/testing/).

When I run only jest like this: `jest --watchAll` everything works.
But if I like this: `jest --watchAll --collectCoverage`, all spec files with the apollo testing module fails with:

```js
TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
      58 |   ) {
    > 59 |     this.numberOfDrafts$ = this.getNumberOfDraftsGQL.watch().valueChanges.pipe(
         |                                                      ^
```

(line 59 is inside a components constructor).

I hope someone can help me understand what this error message means, and why it appears *only* if I **collect coverage**?